# getting push notification click event

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Is there a way to get a click event when user presses on a push notification?

My problem is that in some of my notifications i open a browser so i cant add an extra to the intent for handling click event.

CAN HANDLE:

```
            Intent QuestionIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityQuestionnaires.class);
            QuestionIntent.putExtra("pushFlag", true);
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, QuestionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

CAN'T HANDLE:

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data)), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: Why dont u pass the intent to your application and then get the onclick event and then open your browser from your app (or a service in your app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that u must open a Dummy activity that handles your analytics and whatever u want and then open the browser and closes it self.
Its a hack and an unpretty one but i dont think that there is another way.